# RSS feed for dynamic set of custom taxonomies terms

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, rss

I've got a CPT called 'Job' and three different taxonomies associated with it: location, type (permanent/contract) and expertise.

I've got a filter on the website that allows to search for jobs of specific expertise of specific type in a certain location: http://www.grovelands.co.uk/roles-we-offer

I'd like to create a RSS feed where a visitor can choose a specific set of taxonomy terms (location, type, expertise) to subscribe to.

**For example**, a visitor 1 would like to sign up for jobs in 'corporate development' expertise of all types in London are. Visitor 2 wants to sign up 'Risk and Regulation' expertise of 'contract' type in Scotland only.

Is such a dynamic RSS possible to create and how to?

I would hugely appreciate any tips and hints.

Many thanks, Dasha

Comment: You could try:  `/feed/?post_type=job&location=london`

Comment: you might have a look at http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type to see if your register settings are `public` (the default is false)

Answer (score 2):

[Code Tricks](http://code-tricks.com/rss-feeds-for-custom-post-type-in-wordpress/) have an article on this.

The article is so short that quoting it will essentially copy it:

```
//URL to fetch RSS feeds for custom post type feeds.
www.your-website.com/feed/?post_type=custom_post_type_name

//URL to fetch RSS feed for custom post type feeds including the custom taxonomy.
www.your-website.com/feed/?post_type=custom_post_type_name&taxonomy_name=taxonomy

//This is just an example.
www.code-tricks.com/feed/?post_type=tutorials&tutorials_category=javascript
```

Please do see the original article.